# Power BI Desktop, import data from SQL Database and build a history

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a connection from Power BI Desktop to an SQL database. I only import one table, this table has only one row with columns: Number, date/time, user. Sometimes a user changes the Number via a module in an ERP program.

The row in the Database table will be overwritten with a new Number, date/time and user.

In Power BI, the row will also be overwritten, bud I want to build a history in Power BI, so that it will create a new row every time I do a refresh and a value has changed. I want this history so I can see what date which user has changed the value.

Is this possible in Power BI Desktop?

Kind regards,

Björn

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer.

No. Power BI is a read only tool, it cannot change data in the source nor add an archive. Each refresh is a "wipe everything and reload from the source."

To create an archive of what was done, you would need to either use a Stored Procedure to append data to a history table you create when that table changes, or use Power Automate to do this via a flow. It can detect when records change and add data to a new SQL table or an Excel spreadsheet if that is easier.